# What's the problem here (c program). It shows too many argument s for format. For all the 'scanf' lines

Tags: c, function

```
FILE* f;
fopen("vaccine.txt", "w");              //Open and write on the vaccine.txt file

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {                   //Allow up to 5 vaccine's recorded at once!
    printf("\nName of vaccine %d: ", i + 1);
    scanf("%s", vacname, sizeof(vacname), f);
    printf("\tVaccine Code: ");
    scanf("%s",code, sizeof(code), f);
    printf("\tProducing Country: ");
    scanf("%s", country, sizeof(country), f);
    printf("\tDosage: ");
    scanf("%d", &dosage, f);
    printf("\tPopulation: ");
    scanf("%f", &population, f);
    printf("\tQuantity: ");
    scanf("%d", &quantity, f);

    fprintf(f, "%s\n%s\n%s\n%d\n%.2f\n%d\n", vacname, code, country, dosage, population, quantity);
}
fclose(f);
printf("\nVaccine data successfully recorded!\n\n");    //Notify user of the program successful ru


n
};
```

Comment: See [this](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/scanf-and-fscanf-in-c-simple-yet-poweful/amp/), it explains the difference between `scanf` and `fscanf`, as well as how to use them.

Comment: Do you mean by, `scanf("%s", vacname, sizeof(vacname), f);`, perhaps, `fscanf(f, "%99s", vacname);`?

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to specify size with scanf. You can use fgets; it is buffer safe

```
scanf("%s",variable);
```